# output of os.system in variable python

Tags: python, sockets

I am making a server that asks for you IP address and I want to make an option that says `(leave blank for __your ip__)` but I'm having trouble with it. I tried doing this

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("ipconfig getifaddr en0", shell=True)
```

but it returns
`b'***.***.***.***\n'` is there a way to remove the '', b and \n or another way to get an IP that doesn't return `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: The socket module has various utilities to discover network details about the host. It may be more portable and robust than this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is the bytestring output and the following newline.

You'll want

```
output = subprocess.check_output("ipconfig getifaddr en0", shell=True).decode().strip()
```

to first decode the bytes as UTF-8, then strip whitespace from the start and the end.

Comment: this worked if anyone wants to see the final code its here: [github](https://github.com/thepythonscript/gui_chatroom)

Comment: Right, if all you wanted was to bind to a public IP, listening on `0.0.0.0` would have done the trick.